# Communication between two war files without hardcoding the context root

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, communication-protocol

I have an ear application which has two war files.

In the application on clicking a hyper link the flow goes from one war file to another war file. In this case I'm hard-coding the URL for the spring war. Is there any way I can define it as an variable.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use HttpClient or AsyncHttpCLient library for sending request from one web application to another web application. Reference about AsyncHttpClient is given http://www.ning.com/code/2010/03/introducing-nings-asynchronous-http-client-library/ . It will send the request from one WAR file to another with an given URL parameter.